# Adding Truepush initalization code to Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am using GatsbyJS. Recently I created a file in which I put this code.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet'

const CustomScript = () => {
    return (
        <Helmet>
            <script type="application/javascript" src="https://sdki.truepush.com/sdk/v2.0.2/app.js" async></script>
            <script>
            var truepush = window.truepush || [];
                    
            truepush.push(function(){
                truepush.Init({
                    id: "..."
                },function(error){
                    if(error) console.error(error);
                })
            })
            </script>
        </Helmet>
    )
}

export default CustomScript
```

But it gives me this error

```
ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating development JavaScript bundle failed


/home/lilynicole/GitLab/portfolio/src/components/CustomScript.js
  12:17  error  'truepush' is not defined  no-undef

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


File: src/components/CustomScript.js

failed Re-building development bundle - 5.401s
```

I have tried couple of things but nothing seems to work. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Which line is the line 12 stated in the error?

It looks strange to call `Init` on an (empty) array if it is `truepush.Init({`

Comment: `truepush.push(function(){`

Comment: Wait, `truepush` is an array **and** it has an `Init` method on it? I think the `truepush.push` vs `truepush.Init` are two different things.

Comment: I can't figure it out. Truepush is a push notification service

Comment: It looks like there's an `sw.js` file that's supposed to be added to the page as well. You could try this approach by linking the `sw.js` and the `sdki.truepush.com/sdk/v2.0.2/app.js` inside `html.js` - https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/custom-html/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to insert inline JavaScript (the second `<script>` tag) with React Helmet, you'd need to quote the entire JavaScript as follows:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet'

const CustomScript = () => {
    return (
        <Helmet>
            <script type="application/javascript" src="https://sdki.truepush.com/sdk/v2.0.2/app.js" async></script>
            <script>{`
            var truepush = window.truepush || [];
                    
            truepush.push(function(){
                truepush.Init({
                    id: "..."
                },function(error){
                    if(error) console.error(error);
                })
            })
            `}
            </script>
        </Helmet>
    )
}

export default CustomScript
```

The only change is that I wrapped the entire content of the `<script>` tag in `` {` ... `} ``.

In any case, I'd find it cleaner to write the following:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet'
import { useEffect } from 'react'

const CustomScript = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    var truepush = window.truepush || []

    truepush.push(function () {
      truepush.Init(
        {
          id: '...',
        },
        function (error) {
          if (error) console.error(error)
        }
      )
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <Helmet>
      <script
        type="application/javascript"
        src="https://sdki.truepush.com/sdk/v2.0.2/app.js"
        async
      ></script>
    </Helmet>
  )
}

export default CustomScript
```

Here, instead of treating the JavaScript for the initialization as a string you're actually including it in your component code.

To make sure it runs only once you wrap it with `useEffect(() => {...}, [])`.

(Note that I edited out your private Truepush ID and replaced it with `...`; you'll need to put it back in)

Comment: Have you tried if this works? I did exactly what you have and was still getting `undefined`.

Comment: Yes, I tried both solutions and checked that `truepush` has a plausible value.

Comment: Interesting, for some reason it didn't work for me. Also, there's no `window` object during the `build` step so some checks are required for that part - https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/

Comment: Could be interesting to check for the window availability inside `useEffect` hook. Something like `if(typeof window !== undefined){//do the stuff}`

Comment: Thanks a lot...You made my day. It totally worked. I tried this before by myself but then it didn't worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I am David from Truepush Tech support. Can you please tell me if the project that you are doing is "a WebSite" or "a WebApp".

As if you are building a website then the code please try using the method that @ehrencrona has given out. That is [Code by @ehrencrona](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNbms.png)

But if it is a webapp, we are not supporting them as of now and can't help you with setting it up for them.

We are working on a solution for this from our end as well. We will let you know when we have something that we can give out to help you.